# Differentiating between a Dynamically-Assigned and a Statically-Assigned Property

Tags: qt, qml

This code example is from the Qt docs

Source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html

> For example, the Rectangle below initially ensures that its height is
>   always twice its width. However, when the space key is pressed, the
>   current value of width*3 will be assigned to height as a static value.
>   After that, the height will remain fixed at this value, even if the
>   width changes. The assignment of the static value removes the binding.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: width * 2

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: {
        height = width * 3
    }
}
```

I don't understand this example. Why does the first assignment create a binding while the second assignment assigns a static value?

Comment: that is part of the syntax.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax from that example. Please expand. Would the second assignment also work if a colon was used instead on an equality sign?

Comment: No, the colon is used to assign a value directly to the property.

Answer (score 2):

As eyllanesc [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655230/how-to-understand-when-a-property-is-assigned-a-dynamic-value-and-when-it-is-ass#comment94169497_53655230) in the comments. The difference between how

`height: width * 2` and `height = width * 3`

are evaluated is part of Qml/QtQuick's syntax.

> Why does the first assignment create a binding while the second assignment assigns a static value?

The main difference lies in that the former is evaluated as part of Qml (with a property bind ✨) while the latter is evaluated as part of JS (as an immediate, static assignment).

> Would the second assignment also work if a colon was used instead on an equality sign?

That wouldn't do anything (although Qt Creator will warn you). If you want to set a property binding through JS, refer to [*creating property bindings from javascript*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript) (same article as the one you've linked).

> What is the general syntax rule that makes the first statement be evaluated as part of QML and the second statement be evaluated as js with no magic added?

These articles explain it better than I could.

This is a general overview of Qml Scope:

[Qml Documents Scope](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtqml-documents-scope.html)

This explains how JS scope is used in *attached properties*.

[Qml Attached Properties and Signal Handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers)

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: width * 2

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: {
        height = width * 3
    }
}
```

In your code, `Rectangle` is an Item (also a Qml Object). On the other hand, `width`, `height`, `focus`, and `Keys.onSpacePressed` are all attached properties. They have JS scope capabilities. The braces on `Keys.onSpacePressed` are merely an extension of the JS scope to multiline.

It's not done often but you *could* actually do

```
Rectangle {
    width: {
        var temp = 5;
        width = 20 * 5;
    }
    height: width * 2

}
```

or

```
Rectangle {
    width: {
        var temp = 5;
        return 20 * 5;
    }
    height: width * 2

}
```

Both of these use JS to set `width` to 100.

Much of this is gained through experience. Once you play around with Qml a lot, read a bunch of examples, you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Why is the first statement evaluated as part of QML? What is the general syntax rule that makes the first statement be evaluated as part of QML and the second statement be evaluated as js with no magic added?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer and threw in a couple links for further reading. Hope it helps.